# How to dynamically load <li> tags with database variables into my page according to an array?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to dynamically load li tags with database variables into my page according to an array I get from my database. The number of li tags will be variable. I am struggling to achieve this. Please any help would be appreciated

```
$packages_menu = array();
    $sql = ("SELECT provider, technology_name FROM technology ORDER BY technology_id ASC");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $packages_menu[] = $row;

        }
```

**What I have ?**

```
<li><?php echo $packages_menu; ?></li>
```

**Here is the array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [provider] => openserve
            [technology_name] => fibre
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [provider] => openserve
            [technology_name] => adsl
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [provider] => trusc
            [technology_name] => fibre
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [provider] => trusc
            [technology_name] => wireless
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [provider] => sonic
            [technology_name] => wireless
        )

)
```

Comment: Ive Added the echo , but I realize its not correct

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions: after having collected all rows, you can output the data with another loop. That could look the following way:

```
foreach($packages_menu as $row) {
   echo '<li>' . $row['provider'] . '</li>';
}
```

This could be a good solution if gathering all data and outputting it does not happen directly one after another.

If there is no code in between, there is no need of using an intermediate array of rows. So this could work, even if that is not a really nice solution (which should keep PHP logic and output a bit more seperated, as in the first solution):

```
$sql = ("SELECT provider, technology_name FROM technology ORDER BY technology_id ASC");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<li>' . $row['provider'] . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Now, I'm not sure exactly how you're trying to display it, but you can see from the code below how to put your data in side of a list of tags. Then just return that list in the middle of your opening and closing `<ul>` tags.

$list_items = ""; //declare outside of the loop    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $list_items += "<li>" . $row['provider'] . "</li>";
          $list_items += "<li>" . $row['technology_name'] . "</li>";                

                }
```

Comment: Please consider marking it as solved and/or up voting. I hope my answer got you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do however have another question. How do I include styling to these dynamically loaded tags ?

Comment: That won' t work, as you are overwriting `$list_items` for each item

Comment: I forgot to do +=, sorry. It was late. It's fixed.